# Can a traditional maven based project be converted to sbt to get rapid compile times?

Tags: sbt

If there is a project that is currently setup using maven, is it possible to easily convert the project over to sbt so I can run the application and get quick 'running app' compile times?

I am currently using sbt with play and it works great.

Do I have to port all the dependencies into sbt manually or is there a way to tell sbt to look in the pom.xml file or something?